# bash Regular Expression in if Statement

Tags: regex, bash

I am stumped  at the error I am getting from a script I'm trying to run to suspend my machine. I am trying to use a regex in an elif statement to suspend my machine after a specific time period.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "When would you like to suspend the machine?"
read "sustime"
if [ "$sustime" = "now" ]
then
    sudo pm-suspend
elif [[ "$sustime" =~ [0-9]*[smhd] ]]
then
    time=`expr "$sustime" : '\([0-9]+)\)'`
    ttype=`expr "$sustime" : '.*\([smhd]\)'`
    sudo sleep $time$ttype ; sudo pm-suspend
else
    echo "Please enter either [now] or [#s|m|h|d]"
fi
```

The code doesn't work on the `elif` line, for example if I input 5s, the output of the script is:

```
$ sh dbussuspend.sh 
When would you like to suspend the machine?
5s
dbussuspend.sh: 10: dbussuspend.sh: [[: not found
Please enter either [now] or [#s|m|h|d]
```

However, it should read that I've entered the string `5s` run the code block under `elif`. I've actually tried any regex in place of `[0-9]*[smhd]`, all with the same error.

Comment: Side note: you probably want `[0-9]+[smhd]` otherwise `h` will be an acceptable input.

Comment: You don't need `expr`; you can use capture groups in the original regular expression, then access the captured values from the array `BASH_REMATCH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this problem is not caused by your script, but by how you're invoking it:

```
sh dbussuspend.sh
```

should be:

```
bash dbussuspend.sh
```

`bash` know how to `[[`, but `sh` doesn't...

better still, do as [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) suggests. do this once:

```
chmod +x dbussuspend.sh
```

and thenceforth, invoke like this:

```
./dbussuspend.sh
```

additionally, [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) and [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) question your use of `expr`, and [laurel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel) your `bash` regex. GNU coreutils `sleep` supports e.g. `sleep 30s`, `sleep 2m`, `sleep 1h`. check this on your system with `man sleep`. if so, then this will work:

```
elif [[ "$sustime" =~ ^[0-9]+[smhd]$ ]]
then
    sudo sleep $sustime ; sudo pm-suspend
```

(`^` and `$` in `^[0-9]+[smhd]$` to match the start and end of the string and prevent matching e.g. "uzeifue**1s**ziufzr".)

Comment: Also don't use `expr`. Especially when it looks like you are doing that to split input and then just put it immediately back together again.

Comment: Even better than explicitly using `bash`, you should make the script executable (if it isn't already) with `chmod +x dbussuspend.sh`, then run it with `./dbussuspend.sh` so it'll obey the shebang line (which is already `/bin/bash`, as it should be).

Comment: Omg I love this website. Thanks a lot everyone, really clears it up for me.